# Is an ms-sql/excel connection two way?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel

When I connect to an external data source on my MS-SQL server using Excel, is it solely an import, or can I edit the data residing on the MS-SQL server right from Excel?

I have a user (the DBA, funny enough) that swears up and down that it's doable, but whenever he connects, the DB is not writable from excel. Tried with my account as well, but was unsuccessful. His account and mine both have rights to read and write to the database in question. Is there some service I need to enable?

From the information I can find with Microsoft, he excel/sql connection functions only as an import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable.  Whether it's a good idea or not is a whole other question, but it's doable.

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757892/1668244), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9978614/1668244), or [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1540/insert-update-or-delete-data-in-sql-server-from-excel/).

Comment: I think it's an awful idea, but it's the DBA's call, not mine.

Comment: @user1952483  Yup.  If you want some help troubleshooting why you guys can't get it working, some specifics and SQL Server logs might be helpful... though if it were me, I'd just dump the answer that it's possible on the DBA, and make him worry about how to configure the SQL server to authenticate a user through an Excel spreadsheet (which would be my guess about where it's going wrong - the authentication pass-through from Excel).

Answer (score -2):

Try [this](https://www.devart.com/excel-addins/). You will able to connect SQL Server data with Excel, edit it as spreadsheets and save it back in database

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please provide content **here** and then link elsewhere for more details if necessary.